# Categorify a proof?

Tags: category-theory, examples-counterexamples

I am quite new to categories and the book I am reading is [Lawvere and Schanuel's *Conceptual Mathematics*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/052171916X).

At the end of Part 2 the authors use the proof of Brouwer's fixed point theorems as an example of how one can use category thinking to construct proofs, by 'objectification' and 'mapification'.

I guess this process is very important if one really want to use category to deepen understanding. However, I found this part rather difficult. I wonder whether there are some other examples that show the power of categorifying proofs.

All examples are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of examples of categorification. I think that what you are referring to is exemplified nicely by the work of Baez et al. on categorifications in higher dimensional algebra. There is also the very self-contained and quite elegant work of Leinster: http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0212377.

Comment: Although this is not exactly what I am looking for, it is still very interesting. Thanks!